# How to detect if frame is no longer active after main page redirect in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to grab data from an ugly javascript-only website. The main content that I'm looking for is in an `iframe`. I'm using `webdriver.Chrome`.

My course of action:

1. Load page with `driver.get(url)`
2. Switch to iframe
3. Locate element inside iframe

The problem is that the main page may (or may not) be redirected/refreshed **after** I switched to iframe, and the scope will become "full page" again.

```
driver.get(url)

# switch to iframe
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "frame_id")))

# PARENT PAGE MAY BE REFRESHED AT THIS POINT

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "element_id")))
```

What could be done is this situation?

I'm thinking if there is a way to "subscribe" to redirect events, so every time the page reloads, a callback will be called. Then I could switch to iframe again.

Or maybe there is a way to wait until all redirects are completed?

Comment: catch exception(s) and include in your post.

Comment: it's just `TimeoutException`

Comment: ok, when you catch that exception, try using your switch to frame wait again.... you can create a function to call and re-call from the catch.